# Access to the path 'C:\Sites\content\ServerIpAddress.txt' is denied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a web site that in Default web page of it i try to access to ServerIpAddress.txt file that is on server . now when i run my project on local host it work correctly , but when I upload it on Server(free host) i face with

[image]

error. can some one help me ?

Comment: yes . i try to write the client ip to the serveripaddress.txt .

Comment: Have you considered the possibility you don't have access to the file?

Comment: yes my file is write and read able.

Comment: i felt in doubt about permission . how can i sure about it ?

Comment: A google search for "check if file is readable c#" might help.

Comment: you know , i used free host server for upload my web . and because of this i'm not sure that i have writing permission . is it able to add write permission in free host's?

Comment: Is there a web interface such as CPanel?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely do not have permissions access files on the shared server due to security issues. Consider moving data from that file to web.config app key.

or access the file as a relative path to your site. The remote sever will most likely not have the same folder structure as your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

The account that is being used for the worker process of the web site has no (write)access to the file.

Configure the file (or folder) so that the ASP.NET process has access.

Another thing to look at is whether or not the path as stated in the code is the actual path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

give full permission to ServerIpAddress.txt file. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `content` folder. Click `Properties`. Then from `General` tab uncheck the `Read-only` checkbox.
Then go to `Security` tab and `Allow` `Write` permission for your ASP.NET process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a database? In that case how did you set up permissions for app_data folder? You have to set permissions in the same way.

If you are not able to do that, try moving the file inside of app_data folder and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on .txt file and select security and add network service .restart iis and try.It will work.