# Xamarin Forms - File System

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm developing a cross-platform application (UWP - Target version 16299, Android Target Version Pie and iOS; Visual Studio 2019 - Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0) which needs to communicate with a local DB file created inside AppData. All nice and fun until I try to export the information to another file, outside the AppData.
I've tried a bunch of things with no success and I'm curious why it works for you and not for me.

This is the latest code I've tested, similar to the others and with the same result:
Exception thrown: '`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`' in `System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

```cs
using Plugin.FilePicker;
using Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;

namespace Testing
{

    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Plugin.FilePicker
            .Abstractions.FileData file;


        private async void ImportBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            file.FileName = "rooms.jpg";
            file.FilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            await CrossFilePicker.Current.SaveFile(file);
        }

        private void ExportBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string localFilename = "download.txt";
                string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);

                try 
                {  
                   File.Create(localPath); 
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                { Debug.WriteLine(ex); }
                Debug.WriteLine(localPath);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want to mention that all capabilities have been ticked, in a desperate attempt to get something to work, the import_clicked works as intended and the folders tried (Personal, Music, Pictures, Commons) are empty.

Comment: which OS are you testing it with?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro Edition

Comment: I meant mobile OS :)

Comment: add [broadFileSystemAccess to manifest of UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: @iSpain17 Android 9.0 - API 28. Emulating from Windows 10. It doesn't throw an error, but the location is unreachable [0:] /data/user/0/com.companyname.testing/files/download.txt

Comment: @magicandre1981 OffTopic (that might help someone): It was a fun ride. Some of the capabilities were in direct conflict with broadFileSystemAccess and wasn't able to run the app until I deleted the ones that had Device as a prefix.
On Topic: The exception is still thrown

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: ``` File.Create(localPath);``` -- this one. ``` File.WriteAllText(path, string)``` gives the same result

Comment: @andreizet Maybe it relared to permission about file access.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks for you reply! All the permission have been ticked. The only ones that have been ticked off, are the ones that have device as a prefix, to allow broadfilesystemaccess capability.
After checking the manifest, the capabilities that aren't ticked anymore are:
Bluetooth, Gaze Input, Graphics Capture, Location, Low Level, Microphone, Point of Service, Proximity and Webcam.

Comment: try [Xamarin.Essentials for file access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/platform/files/#using--xamarinessentials--file-system-helpers)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried it. Windows.Storage seems to have sorted my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing **ExportBtn_Clicked** code in local proejct . It occurs the same error.

> Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\download.txt' is denied.
>      at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>      at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
>      at App8.MainPage..ctor()

This problem happens in UWP when accessing file from outside of app . Then I find a similar discussion about this error.

[Access to the path 'C:\Sites\content\ServerIpAddress.txt' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480940/access-to-the-path-c-sites-content-serveripaddress-txt-is-denied)

Then I refer to [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) ,the problem is UWP want to get files outside the scope of the app, you need to use `Windows.Storage`.If have a necessary to use **Documents** folder , you can refer to this to access it.

[Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)

```
using Windows.Storage;
var x = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\UserName\Documents"); await x.CreateFileAsync("newfile.txt");
```

Note: Better using sandbox folder in application ,this will have the full permission .

In **Android** , if want to use [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos) to realize it as follow:

```
 Java.IO.File sdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
 Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File (sdCard.AbsolutePath + "/MyFolder");
 dir.Mkdirs ();
 Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File (dir,"download.txt");
    if (!file.Exists ()) {
        file.CreateNewFile ();
        file.Mkdir ();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter (file);
        // Writes the content to the file
        writer.Write (jsonData);
        writer.Flush ();
        writer.Close ();
    }
```

Comment: All the folders forwarded by Environment.SpecialFolder are Read-Only. And yes, the work-around seems to be a dependency service to allow me to use Windows.Storage. System.IO doesn't seem to allow me to use any folder outside AppData. 
`var x = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\UserName\Documents");
            await x.CreateFileAsync("newfile.txt");` 
This works for UWP. (The permissions haven't been changed)

Comment: @andreizet Yeah , you are right. All the folders forwarded by Environment.SpecialFolder are Read-Only. I update the answer .The final reason is that the limit of UWP to access file from outside of app result it. Here using `File` can not realize it , should using `Windows.Storage` .

Comment: Yes, I'm using dependencyservice to build my solution. I will share my code once I finish. Thinking of exporting to iCloud for iOS, for which I'm waiting for a Apple Developer User from the higher-ups to access those capabilities.

Comment: If you Edit and add Java.IO as a solution for Android, which was doing the same thing, I will vote your answer. Weird that we have a cross-platform library, but still have to use the dependency service.

Comment: @andreizet Do you mean this in android , I have updated in answer.

Comment: @ JuniorJiang      I was thinking more like
       `String folder = "ThisFolder";
            File f = new File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, folder);
            Debug.WriteLine(f.AbsoluteFile);
            if (!f.Exists())
            {
                f.Mkdirs();
            }`

Comment: @andreizet Okey , you can have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos) .

Comment: @ JuniorJiang Thank you for your reply. The application I'm developing needs to Export databases on-request to be re-used on other tablets if needs be, and want the user to be able to find the exported files in an easy to access location, thus, using the external storage, which is not always ... external. Does this seem like a good way to do it? PS: I approve your answer, but don't have enough reputation to Vote.

Comment: @andreizet You can design a file browser to select where want save file like [this](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/data/files/browse_files) .

Comment: Jiang. Yes, there seems to be solutions for UWP with FileSavePicker and maybe [Android FileSave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586691/how-to-open-file-save-dialog-in-android) for Android. But iOS will not allow me to do this...

Comment: @andreizet Yeah , haven’t found such an app on iOS yet . IOS local file browser should not be allowed for developer.